# Rewrite rule in IIS for mutiple domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, orchardcms

trying to redirect a www domain to a non www i found the following article which work great for a single domain (http://egeek.dk/redirect-www-to-non-www-iis/) but my main problem is I am using orchard and want to do this for multiple tenant/domian name. basically I want any domain that is pointing to the server that has a www. to foward to http://domiananame.extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a little module that does this so I have never tried using this module but you could try it out, may do what you are looking for...

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.CloudConstruct.BrowserDetection